# Index out of range error when using a list as a parameter for thread start routine

Tags: c#, multithreading, lambda, delegates, indexoutofboundsexception

I am writing a C# program that requires giving a thread parameters to a function so that the function will run properly on the separate thread. Specifically one of the parameters is a string name to a file that it is supposed to access. The problem is that I am storing the names of the files in a list and I am accessing the value from the list. However, when I do this I get an index out of range error after one or two threads are created. I think that this is list of strings is my issue, but I know that the index is not out of range.

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong with the way I am passing in the parameters or what else could be wrong.

Here is a sample of my C# code (excluding the code for the functions called):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                surfaceGraphDataNames.Add(String.Format(surfacePlotDataLocation+"ThreadData{0}.txt", i));
                try
                {
                    generateInputFile(masterDataLocation);
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Not enough data remaining to create an input file");
                    masterDataLocation = masterDataSet.Count - ((graphData.NumRootsUsed + 1) * (graphData.Polynomial + 1) - 1);
                    this.dataSetLabel.Text = String.Format("Current Data Set: {0}", masterDataLocation + 1);
                    return;
                }
                try
                {
                    //creates the data in a specific text file I hope
                    createSurfaceGraph(surfaceGraphDataNames[i]);
                    //start threads 
                    threadsRunning.Add(new Thread(() => runGnuplotClicks(surfaceGraphDataNames[i], masterDataLocation)));
                    threadsRunning[i].Start();
                }
                catch
                {
                    this.graphPictureBox1.Image = null;//makes image go away if data fails
                    MessageBox.Show("Gridgen failed to generate good data");
                }
                masterDataLocation++;
            }
```

Comment: There must be something wrong in your code, when it throws the exception and highlights where's wrong, you should move your mouse over the list and the index variable to see. It's always true that the index variable would be out of the list's range.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by the index variable would always be out of the list's range? When I send the value out to the console not in the thread section I have no issue with the index being out of range. Also I can't figure out why I seem to be unable to catch the exception no matter where I put try catch blocks the exception goes unhandled.

Comment: I mean the variable used as the index passed in your list `indexer`, for example, it's the `i` in your code. There is some exception the `try-catch` can't catch, I think it may involve some option in `Debug->Exceptions`, you may want to try ticking the `Thrown` column on the first row.

Comment: The strange thing is I am pretty sure that i is not out of range because I tried indexing the list out of the lambda expression and there is no exception thrown, so I am not sure why this seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that you have to do something like this:

```
threadsRunning.Add(new Thread(() => {
           var k = i;
           runGnuplotClicks(surfaceGraphDataNames[k], masterDataLocation)
          }
        ));
```

The reason is that when you use the variable `i`, it's not safe because when your `i++`, and the `surfaceGraphDataNames` has not been added with new item yet, the exception will throw because your `Thread` run nearly simultaneously.

Here is the context which leads to the exception:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
   //Suppose i is increased to 3 at here
   //Here is where your Thread running code which accesses to the surfaceGraphDataNames[i]   
   //That means it's out of range at this time because
   //the surfaceGraphDataNames has not been added with new item by the code below 
   surfaceGraphDataNames.Add(String.Format(surfacePlotDataLocation+"ThreadData{0}.txt", i));
   //....
}
```

### UPDATE

Looks like that the code above even can't work possibly because the `i` is increased before the actual `ThreadStart` is called. I think you can do this to make it safer:

```
var j = i;
threadsRunning.Add(new Thread(() => {
     var k = j;
     runGnuplotClicks(surfaceGraphDataNames[k], masterDataLocation)
    }
));
```

### Synchronization Attempt:

```
Queue<int> q = new Queue<int>();
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  //.....
  q.Enqueue(i);
  threadsRunning.Add(new Thread(() => {       
     runGnuplotClicks(surfaceGraphDataNames[q.Dequeue()], masterDataLocation)
    }
  ));
  threadsRunning[i].Start();
}
```

Comment: That does not seem to fix anything unfortunately. Thanks though.

Comment: @JakeGearhart that's the only reason I can think of. And the code I used is also the `safe` way when dealing with thread.

Comment: @JakeGearhart you should show the code in `runGnuplotClicks`, I guess you may use `masterDataLocation` as some index in there.

Comment: Yes I think it has something to do with that. I found that if I use thread.sleep(500) it is able to go further without failing, so it must be because I am giving the value to a thread that then uses it. I was first assuming that it would not be as problematic but now I realize that the thread must be using the value too quickly. I am still not sure how to fix it, but I will keep at it.

Comment: @JakeGearhart you may want to see the last attempt using synchronization in my update. Hope it works now.

Comment: Based on what I have figured out about the error I decided to restructure the code. Now I just have a string for the current name instead of indexing. Now it does not bread which is good, but for whatever reason the file name wont update in the lambda expression and it keeps using the same file over and over again.

Comment: The queue fix does not seem to do anything, I am still constantly accessing the same file name, I can't get the index to properly update for some reason

Comment: Thanks, it is working now. The thread value updating at wrong times was the main issue, I also had an issue in my other function due to some thing that I was trying to debug, but once I fixed that everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this then I use Thread. I was sure that the index is not out of range and this situation not happened if I tried to stop by break-point and then continued.
Try to use Task instead of Thread. It works

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious problem is that you are [closing over the loop variable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx). When you construct a lambda expression any variable references are to the *variable* itself and not its *value*. Consider the following code taken from your example.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  // Code omitted for brevity.

  new Thread(() => runGnuplotClicks(surfaceGraphDataNames[i], masterDataLocation))

  // Code omitted for brevity.
}
```

What this is actually doing is capturing the variable `i`. But, by the time the thread starts executing the `i` could have been incremented several times possibly (and even likely) to the point where its value is now 5. It is possible that the `IndexOutOfRangeException` is being thrown because `surfaceGraphDataNames` does not have 6 slots. Nevermind the fact that your thread is not using the value of `i` that you thought it was.

To fix this you need to create a special capturing variable.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  // Code omitted for brevity.

  int capture = i;
  new Thread(() => runGnuplotClicks(surfaceGraphDataNames[capture], masterDataLocation))

  // Code omitted for brevity.
}
```

Comment: thanks this is similar to king king's answer and I was able to get it working now.